# Missing data in PDF (for email attachment) generated from Dynamics CRM Workflow

Tags: reporting-services, workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a website running on Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011. I have set up a workflow to run whenever an order is completed. It generates an email and an attachment (an SSRS pdf report) with some order data on it. I can confirm that the email is generated by looking at the Contact's Closed Activities. The attachment is there too. However, the dynamic data that is obtained from the database is not there. I am using ReportExecution2005 and ReportService2005 to generate the PDF and send it.

The PDF report shows all the data when tested against:

- Visual Studio, in the Preview for the .rdl
- the report server on CRM

The Param that is passed into the SSRS report is the OrderId. It is passed in correctly, as it works during testing in visual studio and the report server.

I've also debugged the code, and the DataSource and the Parameter seem to be accepted. They were each throwing errors when the naming wasn't right.

Can anyone offer some advice, or maybe suggest what is most likely the problem and where to look? Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the trace files if there any error there?

Comment: Are you using Filtered Views in the report query? If so, remember that the Filtered Views are dependent on the login of the user executing the query or report, so you should check the security context that the report is being executed in.